# Is Passing Reference From Child To Parent During Construction UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

The following is a simplified version of some code.

```
struct Test {
    Test( int &id ) : id( id ) {}
    int &id;
};

struct B : Test {
    B() : Test( a ) {}
    int a;
};
```

Now, I'm aware that the parent, in this case `Test` would be created before the `B` object when a `B` object is created. Does that then mean that the `a` variable, being passed in to the `Test` constructor, does not yet have an address and is thus Undefined Behaviour? Or is this safe?

Just to clarify, the value of `id` is **not** used until after `B` is fully constructed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes your code is fine.

You can use memory addresses and reference to not yet initialized members in the constructor. What you cannot do is using the value before it has been initialized. This would be undefined behavior:

```
struct BROKEN {
    BROKEN( int* id ) : id(*id) {}
    int id;               // ^ -------- UB
};

struct B : BROKEN {
    B() : BROKEN( &a ) {}
    int a;
};
```

---

> [...] being passed in to the Test constructor, does not yet have an address and is thus Undefined Behaviour

Consider what happens when an object is created. First memory is allocated, then the constructor is called. Hence "does not yet have an address" is not correct.

Comment: Added some clarification on the use of `id` -- it's never used until after `B` is fully constructed. So, from your answer, seems like it is safe to do. The last sentence of your answer makes a lot of sense, and seems obvious after being pointed out. Thank you :)

Comment: @ChrisMM maybe the answer wasnt clear enough. Your code is fine. I just wanted to show an example that isnt.

Comment: It was clear, just figured since you mentioned it in your answer, I should clarify it in the question, for any future reader as well.

Comment: @ChrisMM another weird example that is legal: `void* x = &x;`